# Как сделать, чтоб ссылку выводило в новом окне?

Tags: php, javascript

Как сделать, чтоб ссылку выводило в новом окне?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a target="_blank" href="#link">lol</a>

window.open('?link', 'newWindowName', 'width=300,height=300');
```

Боже, ну когда люди начнут читать книги?..

Ну или хотя бы ищите сперва [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru) и [здесь](http://javascript.ru)

Comment: Самый простой вариант послать за книгами!

Comment: Самый простой вариант - разобраться с основами, которые авторы книг раз за разом упорно перепечатывают, как будто им платят за количество знаков.

Answer (score 2):

Если считать что `target` является deprecated-атрибутом, то можно как-то так (требуется jQuery):

```
...
<a href="http://example.org/" rel="external">example.org</a> (откроется в новом окне)
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('a[rel~="external"]').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
<script>
```

Comment: человек спросил банальную вещь - таргет равно бланк, а вы изобретаете машину времени =)

Comment: Эта банальная вещь была в XHTML (всех версий) в статусе deprecated (в HTML5 вернули), для XHTML strict документов — невалидно.
Соответственно, не все так просто.